# Отправка письма Java

Tags: java, email

Пытаюсь отправить письмо на Java. На просторах интернета [нашел пример](http://devcolibri.com/1972)

Но при запуске выдает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
    at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:230)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:214)
    at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:251)
    at SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:24)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

Вот мой pom файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>п</groupId>
    <artifactId>о</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Но почему то зависимости подсвечены красным. в библиотеки добавил необходимые jar 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

использую IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.4

Comment: У вас поп-ап появлется с предложением включить автоимпорт (enable autoimport) при добавлении зависимостей?

Answer (score 1):

Исправьте зависимость:

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Артефакт [javax.mail](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7) не поддерживается с версии 1.4.7

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в зависимости

```
<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
```

Comment: то же самое. в зависимостях `com.sun.mail` и `javax.mail` и мои выделены красным цветом. не пойму в чем дело